# BeagleBone Black Boot Issue

Tags: yocto, beagleboneblack, beagleboard

I am facing difficulties in booting the BeagleBone Black with the core-image-sato build using Yocto Project version 4.0.16 (kirkstone) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Here are the steps I've taken:

Step 1: Flashed the Linux image to SD card
Successfully flashed the Linux image to the SD card with both boot and root partitions.

Step 2: Hardware setup
Connected the BeagleBone serial TX pin to the RX of RS232 to USB cable (CA-US9), along with the ground pins. Power supplied using the USB mini cable connected to my PC's USB port.

Step 3: Using picocom for serial communication
Ran the following command to establish serial communication:

sudo picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0

```
Port: /dev/ttyUSB0
Flow control: none
Baudrate: 115200
Parity: none
Databits: 8
Stopbits: 1
Escape: C-a
Local echo: no
Other settings as mentioned in the provided
```

output.[picocomoutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lc5k6.png)

How to solve this? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can't use CA-US9 with Beaglebone Black, the Beaglebone Black's Serial port is 3v3, so you must use a USB-Serial TTL converter [how-to-connect-the-beaglebone-black-via-serial-over -usb](https://www.dummies.com/article/technology/computers/hardware/beaglebone/how-to-connect-the-beaglebone-black-via-serial-over-usb-144981/)

Comment: Thank you.i used USB to TTL and it's working.